# DataColumnCollection does not contain a definition for Cast

Tags: c#, casting, datatable

Why isn't this cast working?  `table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()`

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Open();

    bcp.DestinationTableName = destinationTable;

    //map the columns in the datatable to the sql table
    table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList().ForEach(c => bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName));
}
```

I thought I was going crazy, so I tried a test table... Same thing...

[image]

This is the error:

> **Error   1   'System.Data.DataColumnCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)'
>   has some invalid arguments**
>
> **Error   2   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataColumnCollection' to
>   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection'**

Comment: Tried clean and re-build?

Comment: Tried.  Also restarted Vis Studio, error still there.

Answer (score 9):

You must add  System.Linq in your class.

```
using System.Linq;
```